# Googlesheet IF with multiple cases

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

in my Google sheet table I have the first list with summary of invoices which are then separated to 4 lists according to parameters (manually). I need to know about all invoices from the first list, on which category/list they are.

So for example - lists: Alphabet, abc, def, mno, xyz. In Alphabet is column "list".
How to write function which found invoice on another list according to ID (column B) from Alphabet and write name of the correct list to column "list". I tried to write this function using IF, match, etc. But I still don't have solution. Can you help me please? Sorry for my English :-)
[image]

Comment: Because if it is Google sheets it might (not sure yet) be simpler with a QUERY. Also it would help if you could show us an example of what it should look like if it were working.

Comment: Sorry, spreadsheet is new for me. It's Google Sheet - tables.

Comment: Here is very basic form of that sheet. There is also column "ID" in other lists. I hope it's easier to understand me now :)

Comment: so in the example, your sheet abc would contain the invoice ids for the first 2 items?

Comment: In my example there are 5 invoices - 2 in abc list, 1 in xyz , one of them is nowhere (only in list Summary) a the last one in mno. I need to find a formula/function which automatically fill in column "list". So manually there are only IDs in lists and I need to fill in column "list" on list Summary.

Answer (score 0):

So here is an example which you could adapt. In columns E:H on the first sheet (and I could hide these columns later, starting in row2 and dragging down as needed, I put the following formulas:

```
=IF(LEN(iferror(query(abc!$A$2:$A,"select A where A='" & $A2 &"'"),""))>0,"abc","")
=IF(LEN(iferror(query(def!$A$2:$A,"select A where A='" & $A2 &"'"),""))>0,"def","")
=IF(LEN(iferror(query(mno!$A$2:$A,"select A where A='" & $A2 &"'"),""))>0,"mno","")
=IF(LEN(iferror(query(xyz!$A$2:$A,"select A where A='" & $A2 &"'"),""))>0,"xyz","")
```

Probably I could have simplified a little by putting the sheet names in E1:H1, but you get the idea.

Each of these looks for the ID. If the query succeeds, it returns the name of the sheet. If it fails, it returns the empty string.

Now in column B where I actually want the results, I put this formula in B2 and drag to copy as needed.

```
 =if(E2&F2&G2&H2="","nowhere",E2&F2&G2&H2)
```

It says put those strings together, and if there is nothing there say nowhere, otherwise say the list. If it appears on more than one, and that can really happen, you could use JOIN instead.

Comment: If you don't like the ampersands (which will get to be a lot if you have many lists) and things can be on multiple lists use =if(TEXTJOIN("",true,E2:H2)="","nowhere",TEXTJOIN(", ", true,E2:H2))

Comment: also, if you do not like query, you could adapt this to use match